# Inserting UUID In MySQL From PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my `MySQL` database in which im using `UUID` as primary key (Binary(36)) when i insert

```
03aeecd8-d58f-4601-9c52-4fe85cb992e1
```

it appears in the database as

```
30336165656364382d643538662d343630312d396335322d346665383563623939326531
```

what could be the problem

This problem started to occur when i setup my own database server, when i was using the hosting provider's hosted db there it was appearing fine

Comment: Please, show insert code with var_dump of inserted data.

Comment: when i retrieve the data using `SELECT` or show using `var_dump` it appears fine like ` 03aeecd8-d58f-4601-9c52-4fe85cb992e1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are watching values with PHPMyAdmin that shows default binary fields with wrapping with `HEX` function.

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer. I just tested that, and indeed when I insert the UUID into a BINARY column, I see it displayed as a string of hex values in phpMyAdmin, even though they are stored normally in the database.

Comment: when i do `SELECT UNHEX(id) from SomeTable` it shows null(ust asking for knowledge sake)

Comment: Over table with results you could see `+Options` click it. There would be an checkbox with HEX mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

The long string is the result of `HEX('03aeecd8-d58f-4601-9c52-4fe85cb992e1')`.

Somehow you are viewing the ASCII codes for each character in hexadecimal: '0' = 30, '3' = 33, 'a' = 61, etc.

Comment: so i should not worry about it?

Comment: Right, your data is stored normally. See answer from @sectus.

Comment: I got a downvote. I acknowledged that this is not the accepted answer, but it was an important clue. Downvoter, can you please justify your choice to downvote?

Comment: i changed the accepted answer, i dont see a -1 on your answer, may be it is been revoked by the downvoter

Comment: Aha, I got the unaccept (-15) and upvote (+10) events at the same time, and the net was -5, which is the same net as a downvote. My mistake!